# Horizontally fix some HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that I'm viewing on an android phone. The various paragraphs of text fit fine, but I have some tables that are too wide for the screen.

To fix this, what I wanted to do was to allow horizontal scrolling **only** for the tables, and to have the paragraphs stay in place. So I implemented a solution using javascript, which you can see below. However, while this works great on my desktop, on my mobile phone, there is visible lag between the scrolling, and when the javascript runs.

I imagine that if we could implement this using only CSS, that the lag would go away. Is there a way to do this using only CSS? Is there a higher performance javascript option?

#### My current implementation using javascript: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJcVT), [screencast](http://gfycat.com/GiftedJoyfulInexpectatumpleco)

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sodales
libero quis mollis venenatis. Etiam diam metus, posuere in dictum quis, semper
quis orci. Morbi vitae consectetur quam, nec porta odio. Maecenas auctor
molestie ornare. Quisque dictum est eu lorem condimentum, fermentum faucibus
nisl posuere. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam enim nisl, venenatis
quis nunc ac, interdum aliquet lectus. Fusce tincidunt tempus cursus. Quisque
nec sodales dui. Donec sollicitudin faucibus venenatis. In tortor magna,
placerat et vestibulum id, rutrum sed lacus. Nam ut odio et sapien euismod
pretium.
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="min-width:200px; background-color: red;">&nbsp;
        <td style="min-width:200px; background-color: green;">
        <td style="min-width:200px; background-color: red;">
        <td style="min-width:200px; background-color: green;">
        <td style="min-width:200px; background-color: red;">
        <td style="min-width:200px; background-color: green;">
        <td style="min-width:200px; background-color: red;">
        <td style="min-width:200px; background-color: green;">
    </tr>
</table>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>

<style>
    p { 
        position: relative;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $('p').css('left', $(window).scrollLeft() + 'px')
        })
    })
</script>
```

**Question recap:** I have some code above that implements a feature with javascript. I'm noticing some performance problems with it. Can it be replaced with a CSS only solution? Or one that has better performance?

Comment: works kinda funny in Safari as well

Comment: You can make it so you can scroll within an individual div by setting the css `width` attribute and then adding `overflow:scroll` to your css for the element as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it so you can scroll within an individual div by setting the css width attribute and then adding overflow:scroll to your css for the element as well.

Simply wrap the tables in container divs. The container divs would then have this css style:

```
.tableContainer {
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eRh39/2/

Comment: Thank you! This is nearly perfect. Since I wanted to do it on the table directly (for various reasons), I needed to add `display: block`. http://jsfiddle.net/4sjeS. This also has the added benefit of letting separate tables scroll separately, which makes for a better experience.

Comment: @sharth - See the edit, you should use `overflow:auto;` instead of `overflow:scroll;` so that only necessary scrollbars are shown.

Comment: Good catch. I also added that it should only do `overflow-x: auto`, since vertical scrolling should just use the viewport. http://jsfiddle.net/4sjeS/2/